# Yet Another Facebook Connect Problem? (Request Perms)

Tags: facebook

Came in today and my Facebook Connect code is broken (no surprises there, each day brings a new twist with Facebook Connect).

This code which was working for 3 months has stopped working: `FB.Connect.showPermissionDialog(permission, callback)`

The Facebook Popup shows the following error:

> API Error Code: 102
>   API Error
>   Description: Session key invalid or no
>   longer valid
>   Error Message: Iframe
>   dialogs must be called with a session
>   key

That Error Code makes no sense. This code is invoked when you click the Facebook Connect button. In other words, they dont HAVE a session yet. (well they do, but my site doesnt have access to the cookies yet - im calling this method as part of the 'onlogin' callback).

Have they made a change to this API method?

This is the method im using:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/oldjavascript/FB.Connect.showPermissionDialog

Any ideas of what they have broken now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind guys, i found the problem.

The problem is...

FACEBOOK (again).

http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=12206

If you're using the JavaScript API then you will most likely have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

If the page is refreshed this error usually goes away. One solution could be to try and catch this and refresh the session or authentication code.